# CakePHP 3 error message not showing up on login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to show a flash error message by default when the user or pass is incorrect.

This is my code in my UsersController:

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function login()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if($user)
            {               
              $this->Auth->setUser($user);
              return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            else{
                $this->Flash->error(__('user/password incorrect'));
            }   
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

After put some field incorrectly, the flash message doesn't appear. BUT, after that, if I put the user and password correctly, I can see the flash error message in the following view (when the controller redirect me).

Also, flash cards work perfectly in any part of the project. It's just in the login when doesn't show up.

This is my login.ctp

```
    <?php

use Cake\Cache\Cache;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\Error\Debugger;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;

$this->layout = false;


$cakeDescription = 'Welcome';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?= $this->Html->charset() ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        <?= $cakeDescription ?>
    </title>
    <?= $this->Html->meta('icon') ?>
    <?= $this->Html->css('base.css') ?>
    <?= $this->Html->css('cake.css') ?>

</head>
<body class="home">
<br>
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-4 large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'write your email')); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'write your password')); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->button('Login', ['type' => 'submit']); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call render() method of Flash Helper to display Flash success/error message.

You either put this line in layout file:

```
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
```

Or

Either you can call in particular ctp file.

Answer (score 0):

you are using no layout in your login view

but the code that outputs the flash message is usually in the `default` layout where you can find something like

```
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
```

So you can do two things:

1. put that line of code in your login.ctp
2. Create a login layout that contains that code and use that layout in your view